# psutil.test() returns None. How to write its output to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, nonetype, psutil

I'm trying to write the `psutil.test()` result to a file but instead it prints out the text that I want in the file and writes "None" to the `test.txt`.

```
import psutil
from time import sleep
while True:
    proccesses = psutil.test()
    file = open("test.txt", "a")
    file.write(str(proccesses))
    file.write("\n" * 10)
    file.close()
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: I'm guessing `psutil.test()` is producing output to `stdout` or the like, not intended to return output to the user. A function that doesn't have an explicit return value returns `None`. Check the docs for the function to see how it's supposed t owork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psutil.test()` just prints to `stdout` but returns `None`.

You could use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) to redirect the standard output (e.g. when using `print`) to a file:

```
import contextlib
import time
import psutil

while True:
    with open("test.txt", 'a') as fout, contextlib.redirect_stdout(fout):
        psutil.test()
        print("\n" * 10)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Does this close the file?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Yes, upon leaving the context manager it flushes and closes the file :)

Comment: I'm not so sure, since the file handle returned by `open()` isn't treated as a context manager itself. Also, it should be opened with mode `'a'` for append.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I'm pretty sure it closes the file but you're right putting it in a contextmanager isn't hard.

Comment: The [`redirect_stdout` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) uses separate context managers for the file and the redirection.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I'm also using several contextmanagers. Just seperated with `,` instead of nested.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Yes, even though CPython deletes and thereby closes the IO-object when it's not referenced anymore (like when the contextmanager exits and no variable references it anymore). Other implementations (PyPy, etc.) might not...

Answer (score 2):

`psutil.test()` doesn't return a string. It prints a string. A workaround would be to use `contextlib.redirect_stdout`, so that string goes to your file instead of `STDOUT`.

```
import psutil
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from time import sleep

with open("test.txt", "a") as file:
    with redirect_stdout(file):
        while True:
            psutil.test()  # Will print to file.
            file.write("\n" * 10)  # or print("\n" * 10)
            sleep(5)
```

Be sure to use both context managers (the `with` statements), or your file won't be flushed and closed. The [`redirect_stdout` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) uses separate context managers for the file and the redirection.